# I'm trying to display pdf a file that i uploaded django FileField but it's not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-file-upload

hello guys i try to display pdf file in my html page.

i have this models:

```
class HomeWork(models.Model):
  nameFile = models.CharField('Name File',max_length=30)
  file = models.FileField('File',upload_to="files",null=True)
  course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and this is the class view

```
class HomeWorksView(View):
  def get(self,request,course_id,user_id):
    course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
    homeworks = HomeWork.objects.all()
    print(homeworks)
    return render(request,"HomeWorks.html",{'course':course, 'homeworks':homeworks})
```

i pass all the files i have in my db.
and i want to display in my html file

this is my html file:

```
 {% block content %}

<h1>{{course.name_course}}</h1>


{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="{% url 'Category:u-f' course.id  user.id%}">Upload FILE</a>
{% endif %}

{% if homeworks %}
<div class="row">
  {% for hw in homeworks %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br>
    <div class="card">
      {{hw.file.url}}
      <iframe src=" {{hw.file.url}}" width="800px" height="400px"></iframe>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center"> <a class="Course" href=""><b>{{hw.nameFile}}</b></a></h4>
        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center">   
      </div>
        <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

but this is line `<iframe src=" {{hw.file.url}}" width="800px" height="400px"></iframe>`

tell me that: `localhost refused to connect.`

this is how it look in html:
[image]

Comment: if your files are save inside media than use  src=" media/files/{{hw.file.url}}"

Comment: Can you add the value of {{hw.file.url}}